# Dynamically display input checkbox using ng-repeat based on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I am trying to dyanmically display checkbox with labels based on conditional flag.
The label values are as follows:

```
$scope.listA = [
   {
     name : "Sample 1"
   },
   {
     name : "Sample 2"
   }
];
$scope.listB = [
   {
     name : "Result 1"
   },
   {
     name : "Result 2"
   },
   {
     name : "Result 3"
   }
];
```

This is the html I am using.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in listA"/>{{item.name}}
```

I have a variable based on which i need to display either $scope.listA or $scope.listB.

```
var mode = "A";
```

If mode = A then i need to show listA as checkbox labels. If anything else then i need to show listB as checkbox labels.

How can i go about doing this? And how can i make the checkboxes to be checked by default?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a function to return the values to display rather than the list directly. Like this

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in whichItems()"/>


$scope.whichItems = function() {
    var ret = listA;
    if($scope.mode != 'A') {
       ret = listB;
    }
    return ret;
};
```

EDIT:  To bind to an array
You'll have to have a common value in your data structure and bind to that. For example:

```
  var mydata = [{itemLabel:'item1',selected:false},  {itemLabel:'item2', selected:false}]
```

and then in the checkbox you have

```
   <div ng-repeat="item in whichItems()">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected">{{item.itemLabel}}
   </div>
```

Comment: And in addition: add a surrounding div (or span or label) around your checkbox and label and set the ngRepeat on this div. Otherwise only the checkboxes will be repeated and not the label.

Comment: How can i attach an ng-model for each input as true (for checked) and false(for unchecked)??

Answer (score 0):

Scott's answer is correct regarding the array selection.
To make your checkbox checked by default, use ng-checked if the checkbox is checked with an expression

`<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="expression">`

or the checked property if you want it to always be checked by default

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```